# Jquery validation array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, validation

It won't validate and is this the right way of doing it?

All my form validation functions are working fine, but when i click the `submit` button it won't validate

Code:

```
  var pinvalid = 'false';
    var emailvalid = 'false';
    var confirmemailvalid = 'false';
    var passwordvalid = 'false';
    var confirmpassword = 'false';

    //Validate PIN
    $('#SUInpR_UserPin').keyup(function(){
checkAvailability();

});
  // Validate Email
$('#SUInpR_Email').blur(function(){
checkEmail();
})

// Compare email address
$('#SUInpR_CEmail').blur(function(){

compareEmail();

})  



  //Check Password
   $('#SUInpR_Password').blur(function(){


validatepassword();
})

// Comfirm Password
$('#SUInpR_PasswordConfirm').keyup(function(){

validatepasswordcheck();

})


//When signup button is click

$('#BtnGoSignUp').click(function(e){


if (pinvalid == 'true' ){
    alert('Please check and make sure the all fields are entered');

}
else if(emailvalid == 'false'){
    alert('Please Enter your email address');

}
else if(confirmemailvalid == 'false'){
    alert('Please confirm your Email Address');

}
else if (passwordvalid == 'false'){
    alert('Please Enter your password');

}
else if (confirmpassword == 'false'){alert('Please Confirm your Password');



}
else{
    alert('all ok');
}
```

Comment: where is your html code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as shown has a syntax error - right at the end it is missing the closing:

```
});
```

...that belongs to the `$('#BtnGoSignUp').click(function(e){`.

I don't see any other errors in what you've shown, but you haven't shown any of the functions called by your `blur` and `keyup` handlers, so...

Speaking of your `blur` and `keyup` handlers, you can simplify functions that you've defined like this:

```
$('#SUInpR_Email').blur(function(){
checkEmail();
})
```

...by binding the inner function directly:

```
$('#SUInpR_Email').blur(checkEmail);    // note: no () after checkEmail
```

You only need the anonymous function if you need to take other actions besides calling `checkEmail()` - or if you need to pass parameters to `checkEmail()`. (The way you have it isn't an error, it won't stop it working, I'm suggesting a shorter way to do the same thing.)

Also, why are you using strings `'false'` and `'true'` instead of booleans `false` and `true`?